# How to add more than one CSS file using webpack project

Tags: css, webpack-file-loader, webpack-3

I have 2 CSS files style.css and responsive.css , I need to add both the files in head tag , please help me....

Answer (score 0):

is there any reason why this wouldn't work?

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="responsive.css"/>
</head>
```